# Run a command at end of each Frame

Tags: beamer, etoolbox

I want to run a command (writing page ranges to a file) at the end of each frame.

I can capture the page the frame started with at the beginning with `\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{\global\edef\framebeginpage{\thepage}}`.

But if I try to write the page range at the end of the frame, it does not work:
It seems that `\AtEndEnvironment{frame}{\immediate\write\notesfile{\framebeginpage-\thepage}}` doesn't get executed.

Is there anything I can do instead?

MMWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newwrite\notesfile
\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{\global\edef\framebeginpage{\thepage}}
\AtEndEnvironment{frame}{\immediate\write\notesfile{\framebeginpage-\thepage}}


\begin{document}
\immediate\openout\notesfile=frames.txt
\immediate\write\notesfile{Begin}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item foo
        \item bar
        \item baz
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item foo
        \item bar
        \item baz
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\immediate\write\notesfile{End}
\immediate\closeout\notesfile
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is what the [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) base frame template - [`beamerbaseframe.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaseframe.sty) - says about the `frame` "environment":

```
% Normally not executed; only in containsverbatim context:
\def\endframe{\egroup\begingroup\def\@currenvir{frame}}
```

So, if you try to tap into `\end{frame}`, it might not end up as expected. Instead, you have to dig into some of the `beamer` bowels to find a location where you can write content out to your file. The following patch grabs on to an appropriate location:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newwrite\notesfile
\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{\global\edef\framebeginpage{\arabic{page}}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@doseveralframes}% <cmd>
  {\beamer@reseteecodes}% <search>
  {\beamer@reseteecodes\immediate\write\notesfile{\framebeginpage-\number\numexpr\value{page}-1\relax}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\immediate\openout\notesfile=frames.txt
\immediate\write\notesfile{Begin}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item foo
        \item bar
        \item baz
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item foo
        \item bar
        \item baz
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\immediate\write\notesfile{End}
\immediate\closeout\notesfile

\end{document}
```

The output file `frames.txt` displays

```
Begin
1-3
4-6
End
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `wframe` environment to do the writing.  EDITED to correct `\thepage` representation by one.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{tmpcnt}
\newwrite\notesfile
%\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{\global\edef\framebeginpage{\thepage}}
%\AtEndEnvironment{frame}{\immediate\write\notesfile{\framebeginpage-\thepage}}
\newenvironment{wframe}{\global\edef\framebeginpage{\thepage}\begin{frame}}
    {\end{frame}\setcounter{tmpcnt}{\thepage}\addtocounter{tmpcnt}{-1}%
  \immediate\write\notesfile{\framebeginpage-\thetmpcnt}}

\begin{document}
\immediate\openout\notesfile=frames.txt
\immediate\write\notesfile{Begin}

\begin{wframe}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item foo
        \item bar
        \item baz
    \end{itemize}
\end{wframe}

\begin{wframe}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item foo
        \item bar
        \item baz
    \end{itemize}

\end{wframe}

\immediate\write\notesfile{End}
\immediate\closeout\notesfile
\end{document}
```

The contents of `frames.txt` that results is

```
Begin
1-3
4-6
End
```

Comment: Will `wframe` behave as `frame` with respect to the optional and "mandatory" arguments?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I think it will, since 1) it is the last item in the `\begin{wframe}` definition AND 2) `wframe` is defined with 0 arguments.  Thus, when `\begin{frame}` is called at the end of `\begin{wframe}`, I think its arguments will be waiting for it in the input stream.

Comment: Thanks! But I'd rather not use a different environment.

Comment: @moi  I understand that rationale.  Hats off to Werner for decoding the problem.