# \supercite as \footnotemark argument

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, minipage

How can I use `\supercite` as an argument to `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`?

(My goal is to have citations as footnotes and their indices matching the index in the bibliography.  For me, [existing answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/559986) have undesired results when using `minipage`.)

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299084
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Doe12,
  author = {Doe, John},
  year = {2012},
  title = {A macro for formatting names},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/559986
\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
   {{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
  \usedriver%
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\par\hspace{-1em}}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newcommand{\PresCite}[1]{%
\autocite{#1}%
\begin{NoHyper}%
\blfootnote{\hspace{-1em}\myfullcite{#1}}%
\end{NoHyper}
}
%% FIXME This \renewcommand is silly but without it the MWE fails to compile:
% ! Missing $ inserted.
% <inserted text>
%                 $
% l.50 \end{frame}
\renewcommand{\supercite}[1]{2}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        MWE\footnotemark[\supercite{Doe12}]
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        Existing solution \& \texttt{minipage}:~\PresCite{Doe12}
    \end{minipage}
    \footnotetext[\supercite{Doe12}]{\footnotesize\texttt{fullcite} should be here: \fullcite{Doe12}}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE page 1]
[image: MWE page 2]

Comment: you can't.  \supercite is a quite complex command and really not fit to work as footnote marker. And personally I really wonder you want to confuse your reader by inventing a new system. Do you really want that your reader wonder about your footnote and citation numbering system instead of following your talk?

Comment: Pity! Is it possible to reach the described goal with other means? The question is motivated by feedback from the audience (them suggesting full cites on the slide and consistent numbering). So, no, I don't want them to wonder about this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might need some more tweaking to make it look nice, but one approach could be:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299084
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Doe12,
  author = {Doe, John},
  year = {2012},
  title = {A macro for formatting names},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{rsc}
\AtEveryCite{\stepcounter{rsc}}
\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226351
\patchcmd{\beamer@doseveralframes}% <cmd>
{\begin{beamer@frameslide}}% <search>
{\begin{beamer@frameslide}\begin{refsegment}}
{}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\beamer@doseveralframes}% <cmd>
{\end{beamer@frameslide}}% <search>
{\ifnum\value{rsc}>0\blfootnote{\printbibliography}\fi\end{refsegment}\setcounter{rsc}{0}\end{beamer@frameslide}}
{}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203783
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        MWE~\cite{Doe12}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \texttt{minipage}~\cite{Doe12}
    \end{minipage}
    \footnote{\footnotesize\texttt{fullcite} should be here: \fullcite{Doe12}}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE result]